# How to prevent an iOS app from installing every time when i run a test in appium

Tags: ios, appium, simulator

iOS app on simulator is being installed every time when i run the test script. Due to this reason, my app is asking one time password which sent to the email id every time when i logged in to the app.

I tried with checking the "No Reset" check box in appium settings, still the issue not resolved. Can you please help in this regard as soon as possible, because i stuck at this.

Answer (score 0):

The `--no-reset` option for appium will help you.

You can also add noReset to the caps:

```
desired_caps['noReset'] = True
```

May be it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Use `--no-reset` option while starting an appium server.

It will prevent installing a fresh app if app is already installed and after execution app won't be uninstalled.

Answer (score 0):

The following line is work for me.

you can try this for your end too.

```
desired_caps['noReset'] = True
```